# Error unlocking bitcoin core wallet with JSON RPC

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I can't get bitcoin core wallet to accept my wallet passphrase so I can get my private key out. The password is correct, as I have tried it to send out and it accepts it, but when I try on the debug it will not. Is it because of the way i write it in e.g. `walletpassphase(........)600` or is it 
`<...........>600` or is it some other way? Please help. It has come up with -32601 and parsing JSON and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should write exactly

```
walletpassphrase "yourPassword" howmanysecondswillthewalletstayunlocked
```

For example

```
walletpassphrase "password33482" 6000
```

Then your wallet will stay unlocked for `6000` seconds.

(You can drop the quotes if your password doesn't have spaces, but it's always a great habit to use quotes.)

Comment: i have tried that quiet a few times but i just get a error

Comment: @Mark what error do you get?

Comment: it has accepted my walletpassphase  now i cant get passed the next part i click dumpprivkey then it wants me to put in my address  Which address do i put in ?

Comment: @Mark It asks "Private key of which address do you want to dump?" `dumpprivkey 1ABC...` for example. If you want to dump all of them, `dumpwallet`